# Conditional Probability: "Transformation" laws?

Tags: conditional-probability

I'm struggling to find the right terms for what I mean (not a native speaker), maybe the word "transformation" is wrong in this context? I'm reading a paper which shows the following transformation / formula:

[image]

I'm having difficulties to understand why the two expressions are equal. I'm pretty sure that the nominator in the first expression is equivalent to the left nominator + right demoniator in the second expression. But I'm not sure why that transformation is valid, I would like to read about this law of transformation. I tried to search for "conditional probability transformation laws" but I do not find what I'm looking for. Can someone point me in the right direction or perhaps even explain the transformation?

Comment: Hard to tell without the context of the paper -- do you have a link to it?

Comment: I'm only interested in the rules that were applied for the transformation. The meaning of the variables is not really relevant. You could replace the letters. It seems like the following law is valid: P(A | B, C, greek = whatever, D = 1) = P(B, A | greek = whatever, D = 1) / P(B, C | greek = whatever, D = 1). And that's what I don't understand, i.e. where I need more explanation.

Comment: Well, if you write $P$ instead of $L$, that already goes a long way towards explaining the context. How were we supposed to know that the author writes $L$ where others would write $P$?